# How to build big and complex database in sql - IN EASY WAY?

Tags: database, oracle, datasource, oracle-xe

I have installed Oracle XE. I build small database every day to practice from command prompt, but now I want to have more.   I want to have a bigger database with a lot of different data to practice and make exercises.

So, is possible to get a big data file from somewhere and upload to XE database?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get 'big' data for Oracle Express edition as it is limited to 4GB (10g) or 10GB (11g ).

That said, there are public datasets available. Personally I like the [FAA data](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/releasable_aircraft_download/) on registered aircraft owners/operators

Answer (score 1):

As you are practicing with Oracle, perhaps a good solution (which will also generate exactly the data you need) would be to write your own stored procedures to generate your data in a loop (or similar construct). 
You could then generate as much as you like whilst also practicing your handling of large datasets and writing of efficient PL/SQL and SQL code.

This way your data will match your current database structure too without having to build a new database matching whichever dataset you download from the web.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there are sample schemas as HR that can be enabled. See [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25610/toc.htm).

Comment: ok samuel i chekit in the next hour., now i am at work .. thank you

Comment: well., samuel this is the simple intro page of XE db.. what i need is a large file with a lot of different data, i am sure that exists in some place., and with this file make a big database.. or if you now another example how can i build a big db.., i need to now every posible option.. thank you