# Where can I get free table values?

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build big and complex database in sql - IN EASY WAY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147062/how-to-build-big-and-complex-database-in-sql-in-easy-way)

I am using sql developer on my university's database and was wanting a larger table to work with - something a bit bigger than the small 5-10 row tables we created ourselves.

I was wondering where I might find an insert values statement that I can use to create a table with maybe 100+ rows that has various data types in the columns? Something generic that I can play around with.

Comment: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/RandomDataGenerator

Comment: See Ollie's answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147062/how-to-build-big-and-complex-database-in-sql-in-easy-way/7155057#7155057

Answer (score 1):

Generate your own data, you'll end up more proficient in PL/SQL and the data will be exactly what you need for your work.

See: [How to build big and complex database in sql - IN EASY WAY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147062/how-to-build-big-and-complex-database-in-sql-in-easy-way/7292865#7292865)

If you really need data from a real world source this page give lots of options/types: http://gsociology.icaap.org/data.htm

Answer (score 1):

While it's not too hard to fill tables with randomness (or even very *nonrandom* meaningless stuff), if you want data that's representative of real-world content, you might wish to investigate the United States Government's [Data.gov](http://explore.data.gov/catalog/raw/?limitTo=datasets) website. They make it easy to export a huge variety of data into a good variety of formats.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you write your own data generator? It is very simple. Just insert random values into each column. That's it. You can generate a table with thousands of row in a couple of minutes.